# when we say $Y_n \to Y$ in $L_1$, do we mean $Y \in L_1$?

Tags: probability-theory

Simple concept question: when we say $Y_n \to Y$ in $L_1$, do we mean $Y \in L_1$? For example, $X_n=n$ on $[0,1]$, do we say $X_n \to \infty$ in $L_1$? That may sound stupid but my test practice problems really have a lot on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1$ ,and $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ , then $Y$ is  in $L^1$, since the $L^p $ spaces are complete in the metric generated by the $L^p$ -norm. Notice that your sequence $X_n=n$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $L^1$.